# Node JS Mocha Test Cases Not running

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js

I am trying to set up a test suite with test cases.  For some reason non of the hooks our firing, so I made the test cases as simple as possible.  Still none of the debug.log print out except the one before describe.  It is almost like the code does not see any of my mocha test.  I have mocha installed locally as a dev dependency.  It also returns a number of test cases passed even though I don't have that number of test cases in my code.  I have tried uninstalling and re-installing mocha.

The terminal returns
**/test/runner.js
Entered Org Runner
Config setup DB info: mongodb://xxxxx:xxxxxxxx@localhost/icpDB

657 tests. 0 failures. 268 ms

Process finished with exit code 0

```
    const mocha = require('mocha');
const chai = require('chai');
const debug = require('debug');

debug.log('Entered Org Runner');
describe('Org api test suite', function () {
  before(function (done) {
    debug.log('Entered Org Before');
    done();
  });
  after(function (done) {
    debug.log('Entered Org After');
    done();
  });

  it('should create a new org', function (done) {
    debug.log('Entered Create Org It');
    done();
  });

  describe('GET Orgs', function () {
    it('should respond with an array of orgs', function (done) {
      debug.log('Entered Get Orgs It');
      done();
    });
  });

  describe('GET Org', function () {
    it('should get a org by id', function (done) {
      debug.log('It: should get a org by id');
      done();
    });

    it('should throw an error for invalid id', function (done) {
      debug.log('It: should throw an error for invalid id');
      done();
    });
  });

  describe('Update Org', function () {
    it('should update an existing org', function (done) {
      debug.log('should update an existing org');
      done();
    });
  });

  describe('Delete Org', function () {
    it('should delete an existing org', function (done) {
      debug.log('should delete an existing org');
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Just a note, the calls to done{) are not necessary, you only need them for testing asynchronous calls

Comment: removeing done has no impact.  I removed all the orther calls in the It functions and left only the log call to ensure it was nothing I was doing inside any of the hook functions.  But still it gets passed describe and must exit after that.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the issue was using --recursive in my package.json.  One of the test cases was causing mocha to exit.  When I point it directly to the specific file above, it executes as expected.